# Options issue using heatmap2 in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm creating a heatmap with dendrogram informations. 
My problemme is juste about the heatmap options, as you can see in the following picture, the boxes separator in white are not all visible, they are only present in the left of the figure.
Here are the settings I used:

```
graphe<-heatmap.2(result,  
          margins=c(7,10),
          sepcolor="white",
          sepwidth=c(0.01,0.01),
          Rowv = dend1,
          Colv = F,
          dendrogram="row",
          colsep=seq(1,10,1),
          rowsep=seq(1,134,1),
          key = TRUE,
          trace="none",
          col=color,
          lhei = c(1,50),
          cexCol = 0.7,
          cexRow = 0.7,
          density.info=c("none"),
          scale = "none",
          na.color = "yellow"
)
```

I guess the issue is around `colsep and rowsep` but I dot not really understand how these options work. Can someone help me to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the docs: 
**colsep, rowsep, sepcolor** (optional) vector of integers indicating which columns or rows should be separated from the preceding columns or rows by a narrow space of color sepcolor.

In your settings you have *colsep=seq(1,10,1)*, which seems to separate only the first 10 columns.